# Find out the $\angle PRQ$

Tags: geometry, triangles

please, help me to solve this.How can I proceed.I just need help.

$PQR$ is a triangle. $M$ is a point on $QR$.here,$QM=1/3RM$ , $\angle RPM=30^ \circ$ and $ \angle QPM=20^ \circ$ now,$ \angle PRQ=??$

Comment: What you need is m-n theorem

Answer (score 0):

[image]

m-n theorem states that $(m+n)\cot\theta=m\cot\alpha-n\cot\beta$